# How get only a filtered entity from data store

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

How can i fetch the whole entity and get a filtered set of data, as we do in SQLITE DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries) for how to do it in `python`. What you usually do is define a `class` containing members that act as attributes.

```
class Song(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    composer = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

is equivalent to having a table named `Song` having fields `title`,`composer` and `date`.

You can get all instances of Song when you do

```
q = Song.all() 
results = q.fetch(limit = 100)
```

This will limit the number of results fetched to 100.
Now the filtering is as follows:

```
q.filter('title =', 'Imagine')
```

will filter the entities having title `Imagine`. This way you can filter and order your results. Once you have filtered results you can access them in dictionary mode if you are using python.

```
for song in results:
    print song.title , song.date
```

You can also query the `sql way` using `GqlQuery` class. eg,

```
q = db.GqlQuery("Select * from Song")
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) to see how we do it in java.

Comment: This isn't what he's asking about.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries)